# How to call function from another script (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is the simplified version of my problem.
Let's say that I have `loadMe.js` script containing simple function which is returning some array.

```
CallMe = function(){
return [1,2,3];
}
```

Is there any possibility in `ng` to create another script which will load `loadMe.js` script , than invoke `CallMe` function from `loadMe.js` script and return whatever that function is returning, in this case array [1,2,3].
Thank You!

Comment: Put it in a service and inject the service, you will get the function. This is dependency injection

Answer (score 3):

Make loadMe.js into a module like:

```
var loadMe = angular.module('loadMe',[]);

loadMe.factory('loadMe', [function(){

return {
    'callMe':function(){
        return[1,2,3];
    }
}]);
```

Then inject the module into your app:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['loadMe']);
```

Then use it in your controller:

```
myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', 'loadMe', function ($scope, loadMe) {
//use loadMe to get [1,2,3]
var array = loadMe.callMe();
 console.log(array); //will log [1,2,3]

});
```

Don't forget to include the module in your HTML

```
<script src="/assets/js/models/loadMe.js"></script>
```

---

If you are looking to get the array directly from your view you can add your loadMe module to the controller's scope:

```
$scope.loadMe = loadMe;
```

Then in your view you can use `{{loadMe.callMe()}}`